# How to use thenReturn() with a injected @Mock class?

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, mockito

In a Mockito test case, BClass is injected to AClass. I want to define a return value for b.doSomething() that will be called in a.askBSomething().

However my AClass does not have a constructor function so I cannot pass b to a in the Unit Test. Is there a workaround for this?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AClassTest {
    @Mock
    BClass b;

    @InjectMocks
    AClass a = new AClass();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        when(b.doSomething()).thenReturn("something");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(a.askBSomething());
    }
}

public class AClass {

    @Inject
    private BClass b;

    public boolean askBSomething() {
        String result = b.doSomething(); // result will be null instead of "something"
        //.....  
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: askBSomething return void.. how can you use assertTrue on it?

Comment: My bad, I just wrote this for demonstration. I have edited.

Comment: when you debug.. is b in askBSomething, the same instance as in setUp()?

Comment: I can see the @Inject Bclass b in AClass. What framework do you use for dependency Injection

Comment: The problem is b in askBSomething is not the same instance, I have changed it and my code worked, thanks

Comment: Your code works, but doing this with reflection is not good practice. Anyway, It depends on what you want. For example if you don't use constructor and use field injection as it is in your case, a dependency injection framework does it for you. For example, using Spring there is way to tell the test to use preconfigured Bean of type Bclass and inject it when it is needed

Comment: for example, you can create getter for b-field, and replace call `b.doSomething()` to `getB().doSomething()` after it create mock `@Mock AClass a;` and add stubbing for it getter something like this `doReturn(a).when(b).getB();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.
You can use reflection to set the mock in AClass after calling AClass's c'tor.

Just add the following method, and call it in your setUp().

```
private void setMockB(AClass objectA, BClass mockB)
{
    Field bField = AClass.class.getDeclaredField("b");
    bField.setAccessible(true);
    bField.set(objectA, mockB)
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a public setter for b, and call it in your setUp().